# Jquery Adding an element after another if it doesn't already exist

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My dom looks like:

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
<ul>
 <li>...</li>
 <li>..</li>
</ul>
```

I'm performing some operations with the '#foo' div and would like to test if a `<ul>` element exists directly after it. If it does, then I'd like to append an `<li>` to it. If it doesn't I want to create a `<ul>` append an `<li>` to it and then place it directly after the div.

Is there a way I can do this in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo = $('#foo'), 
        $ul = $foo.next('ul');

    if ($ul.length) {
        // <ul> exists; add a <li> to it
        $ul.append('<li></li>');
    } else {
        // <ul> does not exist; create one, add a <li> to it,
        // then insert it after #foo
        $foo.after('<ul><li></li></ul>');
    }
});
```

For reference:

- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) grabs the sibling that immediately follows a given element in its parent. The jQuery call `$('#foo').next('ul')` works similarly to the selector `#foo + ul`.
- The difference between `.append()` and `.after()` is that [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) adds elements into the end of an element's contents, while [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after) adds them directly after its closing tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!$('#foo').next('ul').length) { 
    //not found 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $("#foo").next().is("ul") ){
    // next element is ul
} else {
    // next element is NOT ul
}
```

[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean (true or false) depending on whether the selected element matches the selector. Here, we select the `foo` div, use `next()` to select the element that immediately succeeds it, and check if it matches to the selector `"ul"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $("#foo").click(function(e){
       if($(this).next().get(0).tagName == 'UL'){
           // do something
           // add li to your ul
       }
       else {
           // do something
           //make a ul li
       }
    });
});
```